# "Entry-lable in tkinter or customtkinter python"

Tags: python, tkinter

In python tkinter, i want to have something like Entry to show content, without editing ability

In tkinter python, sometimes i want to show contents that i don't know exactly the length of it
Then i have an idea to use Entry because i can easily move around it
And to advoid editting, i bind an event to block any input keys, except for Left and Right arrow
But, this things also block Ctrl-C and Ctrl-A and it doesn't look profesional either.
Sth like this

```
class Entry_Lable(ctk.CTkEntry):
    def __init__(self,master,textvariable =None,width = 300, customfont = ("Arial",16),state = "normal"):
        super().__init__(master= master, textvariable= textvariable, width= width, state= state,font= customfont, text_color="#6893e2",fg_color="#242424")
        self.bind("<Double-Button-1>",lambda event : pyperclip.copy(self.get()))
        self.bind("<KeyPress>",  self.disable_edit )
    def disable_edit(self,event):
        if event.keysym not in ("Left", "Right"): 
            return "break"
```

Do you guys have any better idea to solve my issue, thanks alot

Comment: I might be tired but I'm not following what your question is?

Comment: just creating a Entry with text "something" without editing ability but other acivities work, example: Ctrl-A and Ctrl-V

Comment: Change the entry to *readonly* mode by setting `state="readonly"`.  Note that you need to change it to *normal* mode if you want to insert something to it and then change it back to *readonly* after.

Comment: acw1668 perfect i got it thank you alot

Answer (score 1):

Try with this way

```
class EntryLabel(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, textvariable=None, width=30, customfont=("Arial", 16), state="normal"):
        super().__init__(master=master, textvariable=textvariable, width=width, state=state, font=customfont, bg="#ffffff", fg="#000000")
        self.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.copy_selected_text)
        self.bind("<Control-a>", self.select_all_text)
        self.bind("<KeyPress>", self.disable_edit)

    def disable_edit(self, event):
        # Block all keyboard input except for Ctrl-C and Ctrl-A
        if event.keysym not in ("Control_L", "Control_R", "c", "a"):
            return "break"

    def copy_selected_text(self, event):
        selected_text = self.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
        if selected_text:
            pyperclip.copy(selected_text)

    def select_all_text(self, event):
        self.select_range(0, tk.END)
        return "break"
```

Comment: uhhhh this code blocks almost every key but u still can change the value by pressing "a" or "c"

Comment: Yes but that is the way to write code and proper coding structure